# Received Memory Warning in DrawRect Method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing an app in which i have **recording of main screen** and `SetNeedsDisplay method` is used.

But the problem is that it takes lot of memory and even i am not recording the screen.

I want to reduce the memory usage of the below mentioned code.

Any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSDate* start = [NSDate date];
    CGContextRef context = [self createBitmapContextOfSize:self.frame.size];
    //NSLog(@"context value %@",context);
    //not sure why this is necessary...image renders upside-down and mirrored
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* background = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    self.currentScreen = background;

    if (_recording) {
        float millisElapsed = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startedAt] * 1000.0;
        [self writeVideoFrameAtTime:CMTimeMake((int)millisElapsed, 1000)];
    }

    float processingSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
    delayRemaining = (1.0 / self.frameRate) - processingSeconds;

    //redraw at the specified framerate
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:delayRemaining > 0.0 ? delayRemaining : 0.01];
}

 -(CGContextRef) createBitmapContextOfSize:(CGSize) size 
{

    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (size.width * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * size.height);
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if (bitmapData != NULL) {
        free(bitmapData);
    }
    bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );
    if (bitmapData == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     size.width,
                                     size.height,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,NO);
    if (context== NULL) {
        free (bitmapData);
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're never drawing to the view anyway, so why not use an NSTimer or something instead?

Comment: Would it make any difference with using NSTimer instead of `[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:delayRemaining > 0.0 ? delayRemaining : 0.01];` ??

Answer (score 2):

You create a context every frame, but never release it, try adding this to the end:

```
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: when i try to add this line at the end or anywhere in the method, it shoes me message for leak as `"Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"`

Comment: Can you try remove `CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );`?

Comment: I tried removing `CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );` but still the app crashes, also it adds one more to the memory leak.